# Ubuntu 17.04 cannot detect Realtek RTL8812AE Wireless

Tags: networking, drivers, 17.04, realtek

Currently struggle to get the wifi working on my new built. I have tried following the guide [here](https://medium.com/@elmaxx/rtl8821ae-wifi-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-04-4c1286524afa) Here is the result from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812]
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
25:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1343]
--
26:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1043:85f0]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

Then with `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7400000-f7403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
       logical name: enp38s0
       version: 03
       serial: 60:45:cb:9a:0a:b9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.29.228 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:24 memory:f7200000-f721ffff ioport:c000(size=32) memory:f7220000-f7223fff
```

I am currently using kernel `4.10.0-22-generic` and, I have `rtl8821ae` in the modprode - result for `lsmod | grep rtl`:

```
rtl8821ae             225280  2
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi                73728  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
mac80211              782336  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: why do you have so much module for the same device at the same time? are you sure you shouldn't desable some of them?  'modrpobe -r <module>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the BIOS of the motherboard solves the problem...